# Passing multiple headers in .ajax request for CORS domain doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function for CORS domain issue, I am trying to adding headers object and it doesn't seem to work. It showing that I am sending headers when I ajax_call_config but when I see network, request headers I only see this

Provisional headers are shown
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/qa/ftest/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36

```
var make_external_request = function(obj, url, complete_callback_fn,
 post_load_callback, other_config){
     var response = ""
     var ajax_call_config = {
         url: url,
         xhr: function () {
         var xhr = jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr();
          var setRequestHeader = xhr.setRequestHeader;
          xhr.setRequestHeader = function (name, value) {
          // Ignore the X-Requested-With header
           if (name == 'X-Requested-With') return;     
                setRequestHeader.call(this, name, value);
             }
             return xhr;
         },
         xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: false
         },
         headers:{
             'az':'ss'
         },
         success: function (data) {
             response = data;
         },
         complete: function () {
             complete_callback_fn(obj, response, post_load_callback)

         },
         error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
             console.log("printing error", jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
         }
     };
     $.extend(true, ajax_call_config, other_config);

 $.ajax(ajax_call_config);
      }
```

Please help how to fix this?

Comment: Given that CORS issues are resolved primarily by changing the server to allow the origin to access it's resources over ajax, what exactly is the ajax adding headers supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to pass User-Agent, with this code I was able to resolve CORS issue. but not able to pass any other headers